# Prevent opening new tab while using two nested iframes

Tags: html, iframe

Hello stackoverflow fellas, I am facing a problem here. I gave a `iframe` code to other fella to embed it on his website.

**Here is the code of `iframe`:**

```
  <iframe height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/iframecode" type= "text/javascript"></iframe>
```

**The above `iframe` contains following `html`:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
//... some html code
<iframe src="http://www.paymentgatway.com/pay" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
//... some html code
</body>
</html>
```

Here above `html`contains another `iframe` which is used to make a payment(third party).

**Problem:**

So the problem is when he clicks on pay button which is in second `iframe`, it opens 3D security page to new tab instead of opening it to same page.

**I have tried** `<base target="_self"/>` in `<head>` tag of my iframe html, but no luck.

**I have tested** using payment iframe directly, when I click pay button it opens in same window .

Please, can you change my luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two important things:

1. Mixin `HTTP` with `HTTPS` is not a good practice <sub>(unless you try to cheat someone)</sub> and even if you do, normally the secure page or the browser will block you.
2. If `paymentgatway.com` has been coded properly, then it will not allow you to load inside an `iframe` for **security reason**

So, based on:

> *I have tested using payment iframe directly, when I click pay button*
>   *it opens in same window.*

**I will say you are facing both scenarios here.**

Conclusion:
You can't unless you own both domains and can modify the source code of `paymentgatway.com` page.

Comment: Thanks, but, do you mean, if window location is `http` link and pay button wants to redirect on `https` link then browser will block it and opens in new window.

Comment: well I guess you are right, I am facing both scenarios.

Comment: I presumme in this case, is the secure page the one is redirecting you to a new page (or parent), not the link itself. (for example, create a simple html page, include an iframe with an internal link to:www.google.com, you will see the *second option* mention here, even is not `HTTPS`, is the page that don't allow to load inside an iframe)

Comment: yes, you are right. It's not allowing to load google.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

?

Comment: Hmm, ok then this might be a very special issue, do all browsers behave the same way? And is it a problem to use some javascript/JQuery? Or does it have to work without?